# getting value from one controller to another controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I get value from one controller to another controller using Spring framework

Comment: I want to get a map which I am passing through ModelAndView Object 

say: return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("index.htm"),"model",model); where I am passing model which is map and I want to get that model in redirection action controller how can i get it?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying. Edit your answer, adding your code, and the desired effect.

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the needed controller into the one that needs it (using `@Resource`, `@Autowired`, `@Inject` (spring 3), or applicationContext.xml). Like:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired
    private NeededController neededController;

    ...
}
```